# Case statements when updating a table based on clicked button?

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a table like below:

```
<tr>
            <td>{{ item.wo_num_and_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.comp_name_and_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.finish_sizes }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.material }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.total_num_pieces }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.workorder_num_one }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.notes_one }}</td>
            <td id='signoff_userone'><input type='button' id='signoff_user_one' data-rowid={{ item.id }} value='Signoff' /> {% if item.signoff_user_one is defined and item.signoff_date_one is defined %}{{ item.signoff_user_one.name|title }} {{ item.signoff_date_one }} {% endif %}</td>
            <td>{{ item.workorder_num_two }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.notes_two }}</td>
            <td id='signoff_usertwo'><input type='button' id='signoff_user_two' data-rowid={{ item.id }} value='Signoff' /> {% if item.signoff_user_two is defined and item.signoff_date_two is defined %}{{ item.signoff_user_two.name|title }} {{ item.signoff_date_two }} {% endif %}</td>
            <td>{{ item.workorder_num_three }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.notes_three }}</td>
            <td><input type='button' id='signoff_user_three' value='Signoff' /> {{ item.signoff_user_three.firstname }} {{ item.signoff_user_three.lastname }}</td>
        </tr>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qwUV4/1/

Here's my php code I call when a button is clicked, everything works well for the first "Sign Off" box but the other 2 don't work, obviously because of my Update statement below which is only set to update column "signoff_user_one".

```
<?php
    require_once('../includes/config.php');

    $user_id = getuserinfo($loggedin_id);
    $row_id = (int)mysqli_escape_string($dbc3, $_POST['rowid']);


    $sql = "UPDATE checklist_component_stock SET signoff_user_one = $loggedin_id, signoff_date_one = NOW() WHERE id = " . $row_id;
    mysqli_query($dbc3, $sql);


    $ret = array('rowid' => $row_id, 'user' => $user_id, 'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')); //date('M d, Y')
    echo json_encode($ret);
?>
```

My question is, would I need cases so the script checks whether its signoff_user_one, user_two, or user_three and executes the correct update statement? How would I do something like that? Is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a loop? Because in such a case, it would probably not work very well.It should work well with the buttons and the specific ids which you have captured.You could use an isset function and use the name attribute for the button..

Comment: Using a loop where? And I'm trying to do it the way you described after setting a name attribute on each of the buttons but its not working.

if(isset(['signoff_user_one'])){
    $sql = "UPDATE checklist_component_stock SET signoff_user_one = $loggedin_id, signoff_date_one = NOW() WHERE id = " . $row_id;
    mysqli_query($dbc3, $sql);
}